# Mouse clicks handle

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to handle mouse events on my screen(outside of client window). I use pure Win32 API.
I have created separate DLL with SetWindowHookEx function and reference this to my Win32 Application. But its handle only window event, and when mouse is outside of window or window is not active nothing happens.

//Hook.h

```
#ifndef _DEFINED_44E531B1_14D3_11d5_A025_006067718D04
#define _DEFINED_44E531B1_14D3_11d5_A025_006067718D04
#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus


extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus
#ifdef _COMPILING_44E531B1_14D3_11d5_A025_006067718D04
#define LIBSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // _COMPILING_44E531B1_14D3_11d5_A025_006067718D04




   LIBSPEC BOOL InstallHook(HWND hWnd);
   LIBSPEC BOOL UnInstallHook(HWND hWnd);





 #undef LIBSPEC
#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#define UWM_MOUSEMOVE_MSG (L"UWM_MOUSEMOVE_USER_MSG")
#define UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP_MSG ( L"UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP_USER_MSG" )
#define UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN_MSG ( L"UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN_USER_MSG" )
#define UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP_MSG ( L"UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP_USER_MSG" )
#define UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN_MSG ( L"UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN_USER_MSG" )
#define UWM_MOUSELDBCLICK_MSG ( L"UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN_USER_MSG" )


#endif // __cplusplus

#endif // _DEFINED_44E531B1_14D3_11d5_A025_006067718D04
```

//Hook.cpp

// Hook.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Hook.h"

#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.Segment,rws")   


HWND hWndServer = NULL;
UINT UWM_MOUSEMOVE;
UINT UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP;
UINT UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN;
UINT UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP;
UINT UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN;
UINT UWM_MOUSELDBCLICK;


HINSTANCE hInst;
//HWND hWndServer = NULL;
HHOOK hook;

static LRESULT CALLBACK MouseMsgProc(UINT nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(nCode < 0)
    { 
        CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        return 0;
    }
    LPMSG msg = (LPMSG)lParam;
    switch( msg->message  )
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSELDBCLICK, 0 , 0);
        break;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, 0);
        break;

        case WM_NCMOUSEMOVE:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, 0);
        break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN, 0 , 0 );
        break;
        case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN, 0 , 0);
        break;
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP, 0 , 0 );
        break;
        case WM_NCLBUTTONUP:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP, 0 , 0);
        break;
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN, 0 , 0 );
        break;
        case WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN, 0 , 0);
        break;
        case WM_RBUTTONUP:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP, 0 , 0 );
        break;
        case WM_NCRBUTTONUP:
            SendMessage( hWndServer, UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP, 0 , 0);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
} 

__declspec(dllexport)  BOOL InstallHook( HWND  hWndParent)
{
    if(hWndServer != NULL)
    return FALSE; // already hooked!
    hook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC)MouseMsgProc, 
                             hInst, 0);
if(hook != NULL)
    { 
        hWndServer = hWndParent;
        return TRUE;
    } 
    return FALSE;
}


__declspec(dllexport) BOOL UnInstallHook(   HWND hWndParent )
{
     if(hWndParent != hWndServer || hWndParent == NULL)
    return FALSE;
     BOOL unhooked = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
     if(unhooked)
    hWndServer = NULL;
     return unhooked;
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hInst = hModule;
            UWM_MOUSEMOVE = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSEMOVE_MSG);
            UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP_MSG);
            UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN_MSG);
            UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP_MSG);
            UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN_MSG);
            UWM_MOUSELDBCLICK   = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSELDBCLICK_MSG);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

//Win32 Application main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include "strsafe.h"
#include "../Hook/Hook.h"


#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);



//Mouse Events
static  UINT UWM_MOUSEDBCLICK = ::RegisterWindowMessage( UWM_MOUSELDBCLICK_MSG );
static UINT UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSELBUTTONUP_MSG);;
static UINT UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSELBUTTONDOWN_MSG);
static UINT UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSERBUTTONUP_MSG);
static UINT UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSERBUTTONDOWN_MSG);
static UINT UWM_MOUSEMOVE = ::RegisterWindowMessage(UWM_MOUSEMOVE_MSG);
//
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_ACTIONX, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ACTIONX));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ACTIONX));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ACTIONX);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd); 


 BOOL result=InstallHook(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
//Global Mouse Move Handle
    if(message==UWM_MOUSEMOVE){
    MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR)L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again?",
        (LPCWSTR)L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2
    );
    return 0;
    }
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
                case IDM_PLAY:
                    PlayMouse();
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You haven't yet once marked an answer to your questions.  If you can't get the answers you need then there's not much point in continuing to ask questions here.  There are other places to get help, you could try the MSDN forums for example.

Comment: Have you never encountered such a problem?? Why Windows Hooks handle only application messages??? How to remake it to handle global mouse messages? I have seen application that do it

Comment: @TaronPro Hans was making a different point altogether: Out of the 25 questions you asked on this site you accepted 4 answers. It does not appear that you are getting the answers you are looking for on this site, so you may want to look for help someplace else.

Comment: Try this:  start notepad.exe, attach a debugger to that, then run your app and ensure that `InstallHook` gets called, you should see activity in the debugger for notepad.exe that your HOOK.DLL was loaded.  This at least verifies that `SetWindowsHookEx` worked as expected and your user has enough privileges to call this app.

Comment: Should I open new Visual Studio window and attach debugger to notepad.exe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WH_MOUSE hook to hook mouse messages only.

Few suggestions:

- Ensure you hook installed successfully (SetWindowsHookEx returned non-NULL value)
- Ensure messages delivered to hook procedure (Set breakpoint to these points or use trace functions)
- You either need to send HWND of target window to the each process or send broadcast message
- For Windows Vista and later processes with lower privileges cannot send messages to process with higher privileges. You need to use [ChangeWindowMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to add necessary messages to the filter
- Use `PostMesssage` instead of SendMessage, you don't need blocking calls here anyway

Comment: Setting a mouse capture is used for a different scenario. You will not ever get mouse **clicks** outside a window when setting a mouse capture.

Comment: Please provide source code that gets mouse **clicks** outside a window. **CLICKS**.

Comment: I have tried WH_MOUSE and WH_MOUSE_LL, results  are same, I think the problem is not in it, please heelppp, I have tried anything

Comment: Nothing specifc in your code. Are you sure your hook installed correctly?

Comment: I do it first time, how can I be sure?)), but I have saw working examples and sources

Comment: I meant are you sure SetWindowsHookEx returned non-zero value?

Comment: Its not NULL, but when I debug its shows 'Unable to read memory', but local mouse events are send

Comment: ok, I've added few suggestions to my answer, please check. Most probably you use uninitialized HWND in SendMessage call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37856/discussion-between-taronpro-and-andrey)

Answer (score -1):

while defining a hook you have to provide the handle for the window for which you want to intercept the signal. Maybe passing handle of the desktop there can catch all the mouse event even outside the client window.

Comment: In InstallHook function I put parameter hWndParent. is not it?

Comment: [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) does not have a `HWND` parameter. The rules you state are completely made up.